# Help complete this proof on transcendentalism

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, transcendental-numbers

Proof $\pi*e$ is transcendental.

either $\pi + e$ or $\pi*e$ is transcendental to see take $(x-\pi)(x-e)=x^2-(\pi+e)x+\pi*e$.

Case 1 assume $\pi$ and $e$ are algebraically independent. It follows immediately that $\pi*e$ is transcendental.

Case 2 assume $\pi$ and $e$ are algebraically dependent. It follows for some polynomial with integer coefficients that $p(\pi,e)=0$, it follows that ... Then "$(\pi +e)$" is algebraic. Then $\pi*e$ is transcendental.

by both cases $\pi*e$ is transcendental.

Or do you think this approach will be ultimately fruitless?

Also I'm not the best at latex so if someone wants to edit this to make it proper I would be grateful.

Comment: you are going to need to use the special properties of $\pi$ and $e$ at some point. I don't see where you are using them.

Comment: Yes as it stands this is generic and you can replace x and y with pi and e, however i tried a few different transformations for the second case and was unable to make a good statement so i left it open for if someone else has an idea.

Comment: Proving $\pi+e$ is algebraic from the assumption of algebraic dependence may be extremely difficult. For "general" algebraically dependent transcendentals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $\alpha+\beta$ may be either algebriac or transcendental, "usually" the latter.

Comment: The polynomial $p$ could be $p(x,y)=q(x*y)$ for some polynomial q, in which case $\pi*e$ would be algebraic.

Comment: @Heimdall Would that then be a proof by contradiction because of the first statement. therefore both are transcendental?

Comment: I was just pointing out that algebraically dependent numbers don't have to have transcendental product. Like numbers $\pi$ and $1/\pi$. The sum of these is transcendental but the product it's algebraic.

Comment: @Heimdall Ah good point. So this argument cant distinguish anything other than the first claim. Please post that as an answer with an explanation so I can accept it.

Comment: I can't post it as an answer because it doesn't proove or disprove that $\pi*e$ is transcendental, so it doesn't answer your question, nor (if I did post it) should you accept it. You can upvote a comment if you really think it makes a good point, though.